# mediator.user is lost after route is changed manually

Tags: node.js, backbone.js, express, passport.js, chaplinjs

I am building a single-page-application with a passport local authentication.
The user is authenticated and returned within `app.post "/login"`
After the userobject is returned I save it in `Chaplin.mediator.user` (like seen in the facebook-example). As long as I don't change the URL manually everything works fine, but when I change the URL and hit enter, the application gets loaded again however with a different route --> no user in the front end.

What I am doing right now is everytime I change the route manually I send a request to the server and ask for the user in `req.user`. After receiving the user the application continues its workflow. It works but I don't think this is how it's meant to be. If you don't wait for the response you end up having no user object although you are logged in.

How can I solve this problem?

**EDIT:** I ended up saving the user in a seperate cookie.
This is how I save the user:

```
  $.cookie.json = true;
  $.cookie 'user', user.toJSON()
```

And this is how I extract the user after the page was loaded:

```
  userCookie = $.cookie 'user'
  if userCookie?
    mediator.user = new Model JSON.parse userCookie
```

You need the [jquery-cookie plugin](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie) to make it work. Don't forget to delete the cookie if the user logs out. And of course I am still open to other ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should store the user (aka the session) locally. When the `Backbone` application loads, you should then route the user to the correct place if they in fact are already logged in.